# Is there a way of writing and reading two linked lists from a single text file in Java?

Tags: java, input, import, output

I am writing a program in java, which involves saving the user's name and their high score. The score would be saved on an even line and the name on the odd. For example:

```
Horace
2203
Rufus
435
Bertie
4725
Lawrence
174
Kane
...
```

Would this be possible? Would any libraries need to be imported? And would the text file need to be inside of the project in eclipse?

Thank you ever so much.

So far I have created the two lists:

```
LinkedList<String> listName = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<Integer> listScore = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

And saved the data to them:

```
listName.add(answer);
listScore.add(score);
```

Comment: Yes, just read the lines and alternately add them to different lists.  When writing, do the opposite.  What code have you attempted?

Comment: This might be one place to start: [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: @markspace So far I have only attempted the creation of the two lists and then adding the name and score to said lists.

Comment: Share your code and we could understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below approach:-
1) Read the file, line by line.
2) If it's odd, assuming it to be user, put in user list.
3) If it's even, assuming it to be score, put it in score list.
4) Use Linked List to maintain order, so any index in the two list will hold the relative data.

You can build upon below example-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //input.txt file is kept at the same place as that of class ReadFile
        File file=new File(ReadFile.class.getResource("input.txt").getFile());
        //User List
        List<String> userList=new LinkedList<String>();
        //Score List
        List<String> scoreList=new LinkedList<String>();
        int count =1;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(count%2==0){
                    //Line is even
                    scoreList.add(sCurrentLine);
                }else{
                    //Line is odd
                    userList.add(sCurrentLine);
                }
                count++;
            }
        System.out.println("Printing User List:"+userList+"\n\nPrinting Score List:"+scoreList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible, but conceptually: that is the wrong approach.

You see, the information that you have there belongs **together**. I guess you imagine to create

A) `List<String> players`

and

B) `List<Integer> scores`

for example.

And then "same index" would mean: the score for player X

Don't do that. Instead create a Player class that has two attributes (name and score); and then use/fill a `List<Player>`

But beyond the question how you model your data; things are really easy:

```
open your file
loop:
  read one line --- which should contain a String (name)
  read one line --- which should contain a number
```

As you can see from that pseudo-code; there is really no magic in there. You **know** the structure that your data has; so just work with that!

Comment: Ah right, because I wanted to have the iteration number multiplied by 2 for the score and multiplied by 2 subtract one to get the previous number holding the name (the odd) 
Sort of like a parallel array system

Comment: Sorry, I dont get your comment. No idea what you want to do. But be sure to see the updates I made.

Comment: Hahaha, yes I saw :) 

Take the numbers 7 and 8. 7 -> name, 8-> score. the 8/2 (two values for 2 lines) = fouth iteration

so:     for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile; i++){
        score = line[(2 * i)];
        name = line[((2 * i )-1)]; 

then I can read the lines in pairs

Comment: Comment with ammended code:

so:     for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile; i++){
        score = line[(2 * i)];
        name = line[((2 * i )-1)];